# Missing partial error that I cannot find in Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm currently going through the Rails Tutorial book and Im on the last chapter adding simple views to the Sample App. I'm usually pretty good at finding my errors but in this case I keep getting the following error when trying to render the view of a users followers and people the user follows:

```
  ActionView::MissingTemplate 
(Missing partial users/_user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :xml], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

When I look in the terminal log it elaborates the error message as such:

```
  app/views/users/show_follow.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_users_show_follow_html_erb___427441195944621571_70028589061100'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:75:in `followers'
```

Line 75 corresponds to `render 'show_follow'` in the followers function below:

```
  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end
```

And line 25 to `render @users` in show_follow.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, @title) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
      <span><%= link_to "view my profile", @user %></span>
      <span><b>Microposts:</b><%= @user.microposts.count %></span>
    </section>
    <section class="stats">
      <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
      <% if @users.any? %>
      <div class="user_avatars">
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3><%= @title %></h3>
    <% if @users.any? %>
      <ul class="users follow">
        <%= render @users %>
      </ul>
      <%= will_paginate %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have spent hours looking for the error, to no avail. Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
<%= render @users %>
```

It's trying to find a partial with the same name. To resolve this, you should either create the partial `users/_user.erb.html` so that it can be loaded. Or you should specifically name the partial to be rendered:

```
<%= render 'user_index', user_list: @users %>  # As an example
```

Comment: Thanks Wes. I'm trying to render the @users variable in the followers function, which holds all the users  one follows in paginated form. How do I ensure those users can be accessed through the partial?

Comment: By passing the `@users` variable to the partial using `user_list: @users` (as shown in my example). This will make the variable `user_list` available to your partial.

Comment: That solved the issue, but now the page renders blank. I take it adding <% user_list %> to the partial isnt the right way? Forgive me, I'm new to partials!

Comment: Learn more about partials here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem as well. I created a new partial in the views/users folder called "_user.html.erb" with this code:

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to 'delete', user, method: :delete, 
                                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem one time. However, upon a critical look, I realized while naming my file formats I made a mistake and that caused the problem. Check your formats and you are done.